# Is there a way to apply upward force to a player controlled ridgidbody after successful collision?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm pretty new to unity, and I'm having issues making the player character be propelled upward after successful collision with an enemy's head. I've tried multiple types of getcomponent.gameObject with vector3.AddForce, but I'm having no luck whatsoever. Am I placing the code in the wrong line? Am I missing something trivial? I'll paste my code down below-- any help would be appreciated.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;


public class PlayerHandlerImproved : MonoBehaviour {
    public float forceApplied; 


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate () {

    }
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider.gameObject.tag == "EnemyHead")

        {   

            if (transform.position.y >= collision.collider.transform.position.y)
            {
                collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce (0, forceApplied, 0);
                Destroy(collision.collider.transform.parent.gameObject);
                Destroy(collision.collider.gameObject);
                GameManager.score += 100;
            }


        }
        else if (collision.collider.gameObject.tag == "EnemyBody")

        {
            GameManager.lives -= 1;
            Debug.Log(GameManager.lives);
            if (GameManager.lives == 0)
            {
                GameManager.over = true;
                Time.timeScale = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene("game on level1");
            }
            //this part is just for game score purposes.
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that you're applying the force to `collision`, which, in this case, is the enemy, not your player. Change:

```
collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(0, forceApplied, 0);
```

to

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(0, forceApplied, 0);
```

More informations about OnCollisionEnter can be found [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html).